# Running a J2SE Canvas as a J2ME Midlet - Java

Tags: java, java-me, midp, lcdui

I have created a Space Invaders Game using an example game + source. Using the existing source I have spent 3 days coding the game and spent 4 days trying to get it to run on a mobile phone.

**The runnable jar file works on my PC but not on a mobile phone.**

- Is there any way I can convert my canvas application to a J2ME Mobile application without recoding everything?
- Any way i can just alter the manifest file to make it work?
- Add a "j2me container for the j2se application" to make it work?
- OR any other solutions?

Comment: it's been years since I played with J2ME but I remember having to recode just about everything. maybe things have changed but I'm skeptical.

Comment: Wow, vintage games! Ohh nah hang on its J2ME! hmmmm....

Comment: This is my first java mobile game I coded... is their any other way of doing a java mobile app?

Comment: If you specify more details about your code, you may get more help. What exactly is "canvas application"?

Comment: Canvas application is the J2SE app like you said in your answer ;) sorry for the minimum details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't run J2SE applications on mobile phones that only support J2ME. It is also not easy to port such an application to J2ME because `Canvas` in MIDP is different and very limited.

Comment: So there is NO WAY i can just alter the manifest file or add a "j2me container for the j2se application" to make it work?